# Entity framework Delete model whitout track

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
foreach (var memo in album.Album_Share_Text) 
                {

                    Album_Share_TextRepository album_Share_TextRepository = new Album_Share_TextRepository();
                    album_Share_TextRepository.Delete(memo);
                    album_Share_TextRepository.SaveChanges();

                }
```

I cant delete it The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity, EntitySet expectedEntitySet) at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Remove(TEntity entity)

I want to evade

```
 Album_Share_Text album_Share_Text = new Album_Share_Text();

                    album_Share_Text.id_Album = memo.id_Album;...
```

Comment: You need to use "Stubs": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

Comment: Cool, but if I need update one row, I need get all values, each one?